# How I do prohibit attempting to build for Marshmallow in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Im currently building a app that will, due to the depreciated `isBoundKeyAlgorithm(String algorithm)` function, that is replaced by the `keyInfo.isInsideSecureHardware()` function only available in API level 23 (Marshmallow), either work ONLY on API level 18 through 22, OR *only* on API level 23 and forwards.

I created the project in Android Studio. Then I told the gradle build files to build for a maximum SDK level of 22, and also uninstalled the level 23 API inside Android Studio.

The problem is that this makes the project unbuildable, with lots of errors about missing files that relate to the API level 23.

How can I tell Android Studio that the app Im currently building will not run above API level 22, and it should not try to include any files that are related to API level 23 (it was some "underlined spinner" or whatever was missing)

Comment: Just to be sure, what is the `Android Studio` version? If it is below 1.3, try updating it.... the 1.5+ fixed several issues..... and created some ...

Comment: What is your targetSDK in the build.gradle file? And have you tried running a clean project too?

Comment: targetSDK is set at 18. The project wizard creates the gradle files with a targetSDK set to 23 even if I specify a minimumSDK of 18 in the wizard, so when I change the digit to 18, it complains that it cannot build the project due to missing API-23 (that is not included in the android-18 SDK package). My Android Studio Version is 1.5.1 build 141.2456560. Is there a way to, as I said, prohibit or lock building for -23 in some config file, (which I then can unlock once Android M gets released to my device)

Comment: "either work ONLY on API level 18 through 22, OR only on API level 23 and forwards" -- I do not know the details of those specific methods, but usually the approach is to support 18 through 23, using `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` to see what version of Android you are running on, then branch to the proper version's implementation accordingly. "How can I tell Android Studio that the app Im currently building will not run above API level 22" -- that's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just because a method is deprecated does not mean you cannot build an app with it. Simply guard your call with a check to [Build.VERSION.SDK_INT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT):

```
boolean isHardwareSecured;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    isHardwareSecured = KeyChain.isBoundKeyAlgorithm(algorithm);
} else {
    isHardwareSecured = keyInfo.isInsideSecureHardware();
}
```

You should always compile with the latest SDK as newer versions of the Support Library (i.e., the current version 23.1.1) rely on the newer SDK - that is probably why switching back to compiling with 22 failed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that you uninstalled API 23, but still using build-tools and platform-tools in newest version. Downgrade them also and try to `Clean` than `Rebuild project`.

This problem also might be caused that in build folders you have still files accorded to newest Android version. Delete from your project repository 'build' folders.

Hope it help